# Convert JSON Object values to keys in a json array

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, reduce

Input

```
data = 
[
 { "name": "AAA", "uuid": "111", "zone": "A"},
 { "name": "BBB", "uuid": "222", "zone": "B"},
 { "name": "CCC", "uuid": "333", "zone": "C"},
]
```

Desired Output

```
data = 
[
    { 
       "AAA": {"uuid": "111", "zone": "A"},
       "BBB": {"uuid": "222", "zone": "B"},     
       "CCC": {"uuid": "333", "zone": "C"}, 
    }           
]
```

I tried this,

```js
data = 
    [
     { "name": "AAA", "uuid": "111", "zone": "A"},
     { "name": "BBB", "uuid": "222", "zone": "B"},
     { "name": "CCC", "uuid": "333", "zone": "C"},
    ];
data = data.map( o => new Object({"uuid": o.uuid, "zone": o.zone}));
console.log(data);
```

it gives

```
[
{
  uuid: "111",
  zone: "A"
}, {
  uuid: "222",
  zone: "B"
}, {
  uuid: "333",
  zone: "C"
}
]
```

I want the "name" field to be the key for each object.

Answer (score 2):

The parts of the output that correspond to the input are all inside a single item in an array, so map *inside* an array literal. Extract the `name` property when mapping, and return an object whose key is that property, and the value is the rest of what's in the object (with rest syntax).

```js
const input = [
     { "name": "AAA", "uuid": "111", "zone": "A"},
     { "name": "BBB", "uuid": "222", "zone": "B"},
     { "name": "CCC", "uuid": "333", "zone": "C"},
    ];
const output = [input.map(({ name, ...rest }) => ({ [name]: rest }))];
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is another way to iterate your array. You can create an object with the names as keys

```js
let data = [{ "name": "AAA", "uuid": "111", "zone": "A"},
     { "name": "BBB", "uuid": "222", "zone": "B"},
     { "name": "CCC", "uuid": "333", "zone": "C"}];
     
data = data.reduce((b,a) => ({...b,  [a.name]: {"uuid": a.uuid, "zone": a.zone}}), {});
console.log(data);
```

Output:

```
{
  "AAA": {
    "uuid": "111",
    "zone": "A"
  },
  "BBB": {
    "uuid": "222",
    "zone": "B"
  },
  "CCC": {
    "uuid": "333",
    "zone": "C"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [object destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) acomplish this easily.

Using your original data :

```
let data = [
  { "name": "AAA", "uuid": "111", "zone": "A" },
  { "name": "BBB", "uuid": "222", "zone": "B" },
  { "name": "CCC", "uuid": "333", "zone": "C" }
];
```

Create a new Object to hold our restructured data:

```
let records = {};
```

Here we destructure each data object by assigning the `name` property to it's own variable and the remaining properties to the new Object `r` with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`). Then we can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to assign the data to the `records` object by name:

```
data.forEach(({ name, ...r }) => records[name] = r);
```

If we check the `records` object :

```
console.log(records);

{
  AAA: {
    uuid: "111",
    zone: "A"
  },
  BBB: {
    uuid: "222",
    zone: "B"
  },
  CCC: {
    uuid: "333",
    zone: "C"
  }
}
```

`records` is not an Array and cannot be accessed by index.

```
console.log(records[0]); // undefined
```

But can now be referenced by key:

```
console.log(records['AAA']); // { uuid: "111", zone: "A" }
console.log(records.BBB); // { uuid: "222", zone: "B" }
```

If you absolutely want your data as an Object nested inside an Array:

```
data = [records];
```